# How to load shell aliases in an alpine docker container with start

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I have written a DOCKER file, which uses as an image an private adapted alpine image, which contains a nginx server.
Note: alpine uses zsh, not bash.

I love to have some shell aliases available, when working in the container and it drives me nuts, when they are missing. So I copy a small prepared file to /root/.profile, which works. I can view the file and it’s contents. But the file does not load only if I manually do . ~/.profile in the container then I have the aliases available.

What do I have to do, that my profile is automatically loaded after I started the container and connect into it’s shell?

```
FROM myprivatealpineimage/base-image-php:7.4.13

ARG TIMEZONE

COPY ./docker/shared/bashrc /root/.profile

COPY ./docker/shared/ /tmp/scripts/
RUN chmod +x -R /tmp/scripts/ \
    && /tmp/scripts/set_timezone.sh ${TIMEZONE}\
    && apk update\
    && apk add --no-cache git

RUN install-ext pecl/apcu pecl/imagick pecl/zip pecl/redis
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing gnu-libiconv
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so php

WORKDIR /var/www
```

Comment: Found out it is no zsh, but sh, which is used here.

Comment: Were you able to solve this at last?

Comment: See my answer below. Can you confirm if this works for you?

Comment: I ended up adding to `PATH` in `Dockerfile` and call the scripts in that path by name.

Comment: Can you please post your solution?

Comment: Posted, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default docker start a non-login shell.
To read .profile file you need a login shell `docker exec -it <container> ash -l`.

To read /etc/profile (or another startup file) everytime, you've to set ENV variable.

Example Dockerfile

```
ARG PHPVERSION=7.4
FROM php:$PHPVERSION-fpm-alpine

ARG PHPVERSION=7.4
ENV PHPVERSION_ENV=$PHPVERSION

# copy composer from official image
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

#set $ENV
ENV ENV=/etc/profile
#copy aliases definition
COPY /assets/alias.sh /etc/profile.d/alias.sh
```

Comment: What is -l flag?

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand, `-l` flag activates a login shell mode.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this worked:

1. Create a shell script per alias. For example, `backup.sh` and `compile.sh` and `dblogin.sh`.
2. Put all those scripts inside a directory. For example `scripts`
3. Add that directory to `PATH` environment variable inside your `Dockerfile`. Example:

   `ENV PATH="${PATH}:/temp/scripts"`
4. Mount this directory in your `docker-compose.yml` file. Example:

```
        volumes: 
            - /path/to/scripts/on/local/machine:/temp/scripts
```

5. Make sure the path you add to `PATH` matches the path you mount in `docker-compose.yml`. For example both should be `/temp/scripts`
6. Now inside your docker interactive shell, you can simply call your script files with their names, for example `compile` or `dblogin`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add aliases during the docker build like so:

```
# Making our command line life a little easier...
RUN echo 'alias ll="ls -l"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'alias la="ls -la"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: How does that differ from copying the whole file during the build?

Comment: IMHO it is more "what you see is what you get". And `.bashrc` is executed for all shells, not just login shells like `.profile`. So the difference is like this you end up with a .bashrc file in your home, not with a .profile file. Using `~` is also independent of the run user. You can do the same when copying the file, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Cory your file as .bashrc under your user's directory:

`COPY docker/shared/bashrc /home/{YOUR_USER}/.bashrc`

Comment: That is what I am doing. In the docker container I am root. 
Alpine uses zsh, not bash therefore I copy not to .bashrc but  to .profile

Comment: are you sure about zsh? I do have an alpine container and .bashrc works fine. bash-5.0$ cat /etc/alpine-release
3.12.3

Comment: @CalamityJane,  if you use zsh then bash configuration files like `.bashrc` and `.profile` won't help. Either you need to switch to use bash, or easier, define the alias in `.zshrc`.

Comment: BTW, the official plain vanilla Alpine image uses `ash` as its default shell.

Comment: Quite sure it is not bash, because I discussed it with colleagues. Not so sure if it is ash or zsh though. I will check that out.

Comment: This link says that in fact .profile is the correct file for bourne shell profiles: http://osr507doc.xinuos.com/en/OSUserG/_The_Bourne_shell_profile.html

Comment: OP states is using Alpine, Alpine uses ash shell, so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

For the people using alpine and root user when sshing, simply add your alias like this in your dockerfile:

`RUN echo "alias ll='ls -l'" >> /root/.profile`

Simply adding it to the /root/.profile will do the trick.
No need to source it aftewards, or have any interactive shell when running docker.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```
FROM myprivatealpineimage/base-image-php:8.0.3

ARG TIMEZONE
ARG WITH_XDEBUG=false

COPY ./docker/shared/bashrc /root/.profile
COPY ./docker/shared/bashrc /root/.ashrc

COPY ./docker/shared/ /tmp/scripts/
RUN chmod +x -R /tmp/scripts/ \
    && /tmp/scripts/set_timezone.sh ${TIMEZONE} \
    && apk add --no-cache git  

WORKDIR /var/www
```

I just build my container anew and when I logged in, I had my aliases. If somebody can confirm, that this setup works I will mark it as correct answer. No clue though why it works and the other didn't.